Godot 4: Textures embedded in a scene that are changed programmatically are not exported with the game
Using Godot 4.4.dev1, I have created two scenes that I use for my HUD. One for abilities and one for keyboard keys. Both have exported variables that contain information about textures that I load in the editor into child nodes. When I play the game in the editor, everything loads fine. When I export the game to Windows or the Web, they do not.
I partially fixed the problem by enabling Editable Children. (See the in-game screenshot below where the 1, and the first ability on the bottom and right appear correctly.) However this has three drawbacks. 1.) I have to enable editable children. 2.) If I further embed them in other scenes, editable children no longer solves the problem. 3.) The _input events for keypresses no longer work in the export. (When you press the 1 key it's supposed to show you that it was pressed.)
I suspected it might have something to do with being a tool script, but I commented that line out, and no change.
I also tried the reparenting suggested in this thread: https://forum.godotengine.org/t/programmatically-changed-scene-instance-wont-save/37413
I tried it with the following code:
func _ready() -> void:
    self.tree_entered.connect(_on_tree_entered)

func _on_tree_entered():
    var root_node = get_tree().current_scene
    self.owner = root_node
    mask.owner = root_node
    ability_icon.owner = root_node

Here is the HUD Ability Code:
@tool
extends Control

class_name HUDAbility

@export var ability_icon_64_x_64_px: Texture:
    set(value):
        if not is_node_ready():
            await ready
        ability_icon_64_x_64_px = value
        ability_icon.texture = value
@export var is_round: bool = false:
    set(value):
        if not is_node_ready():
            await ready
        is_round = value
        if is_round:
            mask.set_clip_children_mode(Control.ClipChildrenMode.CLIP_CHILDREN_ONLY)
        else:
            mask.set_clip_children_mode(Control.ClipChildrenMode.CLIP_CHILDREN_DISABLED)


@onready var mask: TextureRect = $Mask
@onready var ability_icon: TextureRect = $Mask/AbilityIcon
@onready var level_label = $LevelLabel


var current_level: int = 0


func update_level(level: int):
    current_level = level
    if current_level > 0:
        level_label.text = str(current_level)
        self.show()
        level_label.show()
    else:
        self.hide()
        level_label.hide()

Here is the Keyboard Key Code:
@tool
extends Control


@export var key_enum: Key:
    set(value):
        if not is_node_ready():
            await ready
        key_enum = value
        key_name = OS.get_keycode_string(key_enum)
@export var key_name: String:
    set(value):
        if not is_node_ready():
            await ready
        key_name = value
        var filename = path + "keyboard_" + value
        var extension = ".png"
        var unpressed_filename = filename + "_outline" + extension
        var pressed_filename = filename + extension
        if ResourceLoader.exists(unpressed_filename):
            key_unpressed.texture = load(unpressed_filename)
        else:
            key_unpressed.texture = null
        if ResourceLoader.exists(pressed_filename):
            key_pressed.texture = load(pressed_filename)
        else:
            key_pressed.texture = null


@onready var key_unpressed = $Key_Unpressed
@onready var key_pressed = $Key_Pressed
@onready var path: String = "res://assets/ui/icons/input/keys_flat/"


func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventKey and event.pressed:
        if event.keycode == key_enum:
            key_unpressed.hide()
            key_pressed.show()
    if event is InputEventKey and not event.pressed:
        if event.keycode == key_enum:
            key_pressed.hide()
            key_unpressed.show()

This is an editor view of the items in the HUD:
Editor View
This is what the game looks like when played from the editor (The '1' key is being pressed, hence its different appearance.):
Game run from Editor
This is what the game looks like played from a Windows Export:
Game run from Windows Export
I'm open to alternate solutions or fixes to my code. As an added interesting piece, the keys can still receive mouse events. (That code isn't included, it's from another project.)
